# WordPress 3.8 Upgrade Kills New MultiSites

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I applied the v3.8 update recently on an installation with just two sites: www.siteone.com and www.siteone.com/sitetwo/. Worked like a champ. I'm new to this, coming to WordPress at v3.5 or so, and just put up the underling a few weeks ago so I was all excited to have it go so well. Again, everything in both sites works.

But now, when I try to add another site, www.siteone.com/sitethree/ I get the White Screen of Humbleness. The original two sites still work… but anything new I create doesn't make it.

Can anyone here tell me how to go about fixing this? Reinstall v3.8? (In which order? firstsite, secondsite? Secondsite, firstsite?) or go spelunking through the .php pages? (Which ones, please?)

I've done a lot of Dreamweaver (from v2) and PHP (from v4) and MySQL, but I'm severely new to WordPress and would like to understand how to go about debugging this thing.

Thanks!

Comment: We need more info. Is PHP logging on? What does error log say?

Comment: Thanks, @Ennui.
 
    PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /hermes
    /web04/b1869/moo.flat-w/staging/emailform.php on line 39
    20131007T182952: flat-w.fatcow.com/ss_blank.php
    suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
    20131026T181440: www.flat-water.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php
    WordPress database error Duplicate column name 'signup_id' for
    query ALTER TABLE wp_signups ADD signup_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
    AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST made by wp_upgrade, pre_schema_upgrade

Comment: I thought I'd read that if I indented four spaces it would make a code block. Sorry.

Comment: WordPress database error Table 'wp_users' already exists for query CREATE TABLE wp_users (
  ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_l
20131030T224624: www.flat-water.com/wp-cron.php
PHP Warning:  version_compare() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /hermes/walnaweb02a/b1869/moo.flat-w/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 2138

Comment: What server setup are you running?

Comment: I assume it's Apache. I don't really know, though. I've never gotten that deep into things, just sent FatCow my credit card number every year.